# Connecting mysql with vc++

Tags: mysql, visual-c++

I am Trying to connect mysql to vc++ from last 7 days.
But nobody here to give me exaclty answer what i required.

I just want to make a simple connection from mysql.
Please tell me what are the requirement i will be needed.
from my sense I have downloaded Visual c++ Developer tool.
mysql serve for handing database and table.
And lastly mysql connector for c++.
i have done everything even the simple code i have executed.
I am almost irrirated by this 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html

because its not given properly should i need to add mysql main include and opt directory or or mysqlconnector directory because both are having same file.

My code is

```
// MYSqlTesting3.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<winsock.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include "mysql_driver.h" 
#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 sql::Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;
  sql::Statement *stmt;
  sql::ResultSet *res;
  sql::PreparedStatement *pstmt;

/* Create a connection */
  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
  /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
  con->setSchema("test");

  stmt = con->createStatement();
  stmt->execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test");
  stmt->execute("CREATE TABLE test(id INT)");
  delete stmt;


//  delete con;

    return 0;
}
```

My error

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _get_driver_instance referenced in function _wmain
```

What else i need to do. I am seeking even everyforum help.But no website has given me any output.
and in this link
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html
if i am choosing my mysql server include and lib directory for the following.
from where 'mysqlcppconn.dll' will come.Because it i dont write it will unable to link.
I have searchd every website which can show a successfull example to link mysql with c++ with problem requirement.
Even for this 
" sql::Driver *driver;"
Intellisense is not showing anything.

Please help to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error you posted is related to linker.Did you include libmysql.lib or mysqlcppconn.lib as additional library in your project?

you can also try

```
#pragma comment(lib,"libmysql.lib")
```

or

```
#pragma comment(lib,"mysqlcppconn.lib")
```

Be sure that lib file is in configured library directory

Comment: i have tried even that also by following the link.after that error is coming" LNK1104: cannot open file 'libmysql.lib'". Now i dont know where i should add library of connector directory or mysql installation directory.

Comment: That easy.just put lib file anywhere but do this: Project -> Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library directories.Put folder there and rebuild.

Comment: i have tried even that also by following the link.after that error is coming" LNK1104: cannot open file 'libmysql.lib'". Now i dont know where i should add library of c++/connector directory or mysql installation directory.Because one problem i sthere if I am including the installed connector/c++. it is having only 'mysqlcppconn.lib' and 'mysqlcppconn.dll' not libmysql.lib. And if i am including the libaray of main mysql server it is having only 'libmysql.lib' not not 'mysqlcppconn.lib'.Thats why i am in very confusion which libaray i need to include.

Comment: All information you need is already there : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html. You should link both mysqlcppconn-static.lib and libmysql.lib.

Comment: Please read my above comment very carefully then reply.now i am getting error 'cannot open file 'mysqlcppconn.lib''

Comment: I have copied 'mysqlcppconn.dll' file to c:\windows.Even it is not Resolved.

Comment: The INstruction is given"Copy mysqlcppconn.dll to the same directory as the application. Alternatively, extend the PATH environment variable using SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\path\to\cpp. Alternatively, you can copy mysqlcppconn.dll to the Windows installation Directory, typically c:\windows." So I have copied my 'mysqlcppconn.dll'' to My Project file and C:winodws directory and left the option of extending in the path.

Comment: You're talking about DLL, but you got error 'cannot open file 'mysqlcppconn.lib'.This means that it has nothing to do with location of DLL, it important for runtime, not compile/link time.Once again, check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html, step 10,11 and 12